# Wrong Date Format In Form Field

Tags: javascript, forms, date, autofill

I posted a similar question last night, unfortunately I included the wrong code to get the help I need. Let me try again.

I am trying to autofill a 'date' field in my web form so the user doesn't have to enter it.

Currently, I am using the code below in the form field, which works fine, except it doesn't provide the date in the correct format for my particular needs.

```
    <input id="date" name="date"><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('date').value = Date();</script>
```

The code above produces a result like this:

Wed Mar 22 2017 00:59:21 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

I would rather the result was like this:

Wednesday March 22, 2017

Comment: Have a look at [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), they have loads of easy ways to format dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
(function() {
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
    return months[ this.getMonth() ];
};
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    return days[ this.getDay() ];
};
})();

var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDayName();
var month = now.getMonthName();
var date = now.getDate();
var year = now.getFullYear()
 
 document.getElementById('date').value = day + ' ' + month + ' ' + date + ', ' + year;
```

```html
<body>
<input class="fieldsRt" id="date" name="date">
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Harsheet. I already have that code. and as a js file. And it works fine if I call it into another part of my site using a php include code.

But it isn't working in the form field. Not as simply as your example is.

Comment: How is the form field identifying that script as 'date'? and where should I include that js code? Same page? diff page? etc....

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your question. You can include that js code anywhere, means in the script tag or in a separate js file as well.

Comment: IDK.... still can't figure it out. I put your code in the head of the page, and did the form field exactly like you did.....

Its not populating the field at all. Field is blank.

Comment: Can you add a snippet with the exact code you have?

Comment: The form is here:

http://www.rebelplanetnews.com/article-form2.php

Comment: Are you sure you have added the correct script?

Comment: Yes.... I added your code correctly. And it does work. Thank you for that.

However, the code only works if I put the full <script> inline with the input field.

I tried putting the <script> in the head, and it didn't work.

What I would like to do is put that script in an external file and call it with a shorter code inline.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried adding the js code in a separate file and then calling it in your page in the head section?

Comment: Yes, I have. But somewhere between that and making it appear in the field (prepopulated), something isn't working

I guess I need someone to outline it in all three parts for me since I can't seem to get my mind around it today.

1.) The external file
2.) The head code
3.) The code that goes inline to populate the field.

Comment: Can you try by adding all the js code in window.onload = (the above function).

Comment: Thanks man. I'm having a stressful day today. I can't even think straight enough to concentrate on figuring this out right now. I'll just have to use the long code in the form for now and maybe come back to it later when I'm fresh.

Comment: That's alright, but do try my suggestion once. Hope it works!